# Dynamic scraping and parsing

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, vim, scripting

**Original Question rephrased:**

I know a good amount PHP, Js, CSS, OOP and have recently honed my regex skills by using the vim editor's netrw and elinks plugins to download a series of web pages (about a million lines) that were parsed and made ready for uploading into my website.  I work on a linux/ubuntu system, a localhost setup and this particular project is implementing the Concrete5 cms - which is written in PHP.

Seeing the benefits of scraping and parsing information, I would like to have my site dynamically perform this function, though on a much smaller scale; such as, enabling my new user to transfer their personal information from another website into mine - which will typically be under a secure connection (though not always) and password.

**Question:** What is the best tool (scripting language) to use for this?  I do not know either Perl or Ruby but I believe either one of those would be a good choice. I have also heard AWK and SED.  I'm sure I can figure out HOW to do it once I begin studying the language.  I would really appreciate some experienced input on which language would be the best to begin investing my time into learning it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The description is so vague that it's difficult to comprehend what exactly you want to achieve, whose system is involved and data go from where to where. You neglected to explain Netra and netrw. – It is certainly possible to automate site scraping/parsing without the need to involve an editor, in fact Perl and Ruby excel at this task. [Stack Overflow is meant for specific questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), break up your problem into small chunks.

Comment: Why are you using vim for this instead of some scripting language? Or use `elinks` directly and then parse the output with `sed`? While it's probably possible with vim, there are far better tools for doing something like this.

Comment: You said “perl” in tags. Why don’t you use LWP and HTML::Parser?

Comment: @daxim the comments I am getting from others are helping to narrow my understanding of my needs - hence the question in the first place.  Netrw and elinks are plugins for the vim editor.

Comment: @DavidBrown I used vim to parse a million lines of code, using it taught me the regex patterns and how to perform such a step.  When considering the idea of implementing a dynamic scraping/parsing of content per the OP I thought there would be a better way - such as Perl or Ruby.  I have no experience with either of those languages but I could probably pick it up pretty quick with my knowledge of PHP and regex work I did in vim (which I understand is slightly different in other languages but not by much).  Can you advise on what tools would work best to accomplish the OP?

Comment: @ZyX I tagged Perl out of a guess that either it or Ruby would be a likely option to perform the OP.  I have no experience with either of those languages and my post was to try and ascertain which would be a better tool for the OP and perhaps get some advice on where to start.

Comment: I would recommend [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for those using Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl has two very nice ready-to-use tools for scraping that I know of: [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/module/Web%3a%3aScraper) and [Scrappy](https://metacpan.org/module/Scrappy). Both are able to work with CSS3 and XPath selectors for identifying elements; Scrappy builds on Web::Scraper and adds integrated scraping and crawling, with a nice URL-matching system to select the links to follow to gather more information, (while Web::Scraper works with a single document). It moves between pages using the well-established and robust [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) library, which is smart, reliable, and aware of authentication and cookies.

If you want to get into the lower level yourself, there are a lot of good tools to build on, including the aforementioned WWW::Mechanize, [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder), [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath), [HTML::TableExtractor](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTableExtractor) and more.

Comment: Thanks for this info, @hobbs  For extracting smaller amounts of content it appears this will work fine.  In a larger extraction process I had vim use it's marking functionality to loop over aspects of the document in intervals - essentially building information by grouping them from various points in the document and putting together a final string for uploading - cycling a few thousand times.  It does not look like that's going to be possible to do it dynamically using Perl(?)  (But I'm still reading.)  Thanks for getting me started.

Comment: WOOPS!  I spoke too soon (I think).  @hobbs I've been reading about Perl, perlmods and the modules you mentioned.  I thank you for this guidance.  If possible, could you post an explanation on how you access a page, get the xpath of the DOM and assign values to variables? Just a starter course.  I've having issues pulling the trigger.  :)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for web scraping. (See the non-test related examples toward the bottom of the capybara page).   Reasons:

- Simple, short scraping syntax, cookie support, js support.
- Ruby has many other uses, a friendly syntax, and an active job market.
- Capybara has multiple supported drivers. You can run a real browser (visibly), a real browser  headlessly (invisibly) so javascript sites work. With the same code, you can toggle the driver to run http requests with no js (mechanize) for speed. This helps you overcome many hurdles (like needing to run JS/Ajax), needing to see the interaction, etc. with a change to  a single line of code (Capybara.current_driver = :some_driver).

Drivers:  [Capybara-Webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), [Capybara-Mechanize](https://github.com/jeroenvandijk/capybara-mechanize)

- Ability to use CS, or Xpath selectors, whatever you're comfortable with.
- Active development, and an ecosystem growing rapidly around the underlying technologies.