# Screen scraping: Automating a vim script

Tags: perl, vim, screen-scraping, mechanize

In vim, I loaded a series of web pages (one at a time) into a vim buffer (using the vim netrw plugin) and then parsed the html (using the vim elinks plugin).  All good.  I then wrote a series of vim scripts using regexes with a final result of a few thousand lines where each line was formatted correctly (csv) for uploading into a database.

In order to do that I had to use vim's marking functionality so that I could loop over specific points of the document and reassemble it back together into one csv line.  Now, I am considering automating this by using Perl's "Mechanize" library of classes (UserAgent, etc).

**Questions:**

1. Can vim's ability to "mark" sections of a document (in order to
   perform substitutions on) be accomplished in Perl?
2. It was suggested to use "elinks" directly - which I take to mean to
   load the page into a headless browser using ellinks and perform Perl
   scripts on the content from there(?)
3. If that's correct, would there become a deployment problem with
   elinks when I migrate the site from my localhost LAMP stack setup to
   a hosting company like Bluehost?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

TYRING TO MIGRATE KNOWLEDGE FROM VIM TO PERL:

If @flesk (below) is right, then how would I go about performing this routine (written in vim) that "marks" lines in a text file ("i" and "j") and then uses that as a range ('i,'j) to perform the last two substitutions?

```
:g/^\s*\h/d|let@"=substitute(@"[:-2],'\s\+and\s\+',',','')|ki|/\n\s*\h\|\%$/kj|
\   'i,'js/^\s*\(\d\+\)\s\+-\s\+The/\=@".','.submatch(1).','/|'i,'js/\s\+//g
```

I am not seeing this capability in the perldoc perlre manual.  Am I missing either a module or some basic Perl understanding of m/ or qr/  ??

Comment: There's no need to use elinks at all. Perl is easily able to do all the things you describe, and since you don't need anything besides core modules, you should be able to migrate it to any host that supports Perl.

Comment: This is a follow-up from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852948/dynamic-scraping-and-parsing

Comment: What about converting the whole data (after the aforementioned transformations) into a single CSV file (optionally separating different sections by a special line, empty, for example), and then loading it in Perl to operate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure all you need is some kind of *HTML parser*. For example I'm using [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath).